# Settings Editor for #develop?

Tags: c#, settings, sharpdevelop

Using Visual C# Express, if I double-click on the Properties/Settings.settings file, I automagically got a special settings editor.  Doing the same under #develop just results in a standard editor, and it looks like Settings.Designer.cs doesn't get updated, so that has to be updated by hand as well.  Is there a plug-in for #develop that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharpDevelop is a good free IDE that has a lot of good functionality I wish was in VS2008 pro, Test Coverage comes to mind, but being an open source project somethings are missing, a lot of the special editors for example, I think for the most part this is because the audience it's intended for doesn't use them.

The nice thing is this if it's important to you, you can write a plug-in and give back to the community.

Answer (score 0):

SharpDevelop likely doesn't have a specific editor/designer implementation for ".settings" files. Looking at [their wiki](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/Default.aspx?Page=FeaturesWeSolicitHelpFor) it looks like they are asking for help with a Settings Designer for #develop...